# Debian 10 not in grub menu

Tags: linux, debian, grub

I was rebooting my computer because it was being really slow. On boot, the GRUB menu wasn't showing my installation. only windows. (also my windows installation got messed up awhile ago, so I can't use that)  Maybe a drive died, maybe I need to reinstall grub, but I don't know how I can access the command line if I can't even boot into linux.

Tell me if you need more info!

Comment: we need for you to tell us what is your question, so that someone here can answer it

Comment: My question is simply is there any way to get my PC to boot

Comment: think .... how do you boot linux on a PC that does not have linux installed?

Comment: Linux is installed, or, as it seems, it was until a few hours ago. (or maybe grub is just not showing it)

Comment: that's irrelevant to what i said

Comment: oh. yea I didn't think about that. Well I said in my question "but I don't know how I can access the command line if I can't even boot into linux." so what I was saying is I don't think my computer randomly decided to delete linux. I feel it's a hardware thing.

Comment: Can you boot recovery mode from grub menu? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: ok. I cannot boot recovery mode because linux isn't even in the grub menu. it disappeared. I'll try this boot repair thing tmr because it's getting kinda late. I'll update once I try.

Comment: Note that during this weekend, the [BootHole vulnerability was published](https://eclypsium.com/2020/07/29/theres-a-hole-in-the-boot/) and patches for it were released, likely triggering an automatic bootloader re-installation attempt on UEFI systems. If your system boots with UEFI and needs special configuration steps (e.g. you're removed all the default Secure Boot keys and replaced them with your own), such an update may have caused this problem.